# XAudio2 Как многократно воспроизвести один и тот же звук?

Tags: c++, аудио, directx

Что есть:
На основе примеров из DirectX SDK сделал пару классов для звука, с использованием XAPO(audio processin object).

1. SoundBase, для инициализации самого XAudio2
2. SoundObject, для звуков.

Загрузка звука

```
bool    SoundObject::Initialization( wchar_t* fn ){
    HRESULT hr;
    if( FAILED( hr = wav.Open( fn, NULL, WAVEFILE_READ ) ) ){
        wprintf( L"Failed reading WAV file: %#X (%s)\n", hr, L"res/s/test.wav" );
        return false;
    }
    pwfx = wav.GetFormat();
    cbWaveSize = wav.GetSize();
    pbWaveData = new BYTE[ cbWaveSize ];
    if( FAILED( hr = wav.Read( pbWaveData, cbWaveSize, &cbWaveSize ) ) ){
        wprintf( L"Failed to read WAV data: %#X\n", hr );
        SAFE_DELETE_ARRAY( pbWaveData );
        return false;
    }


    if( FAILED( hr = this->m_base->GetIXAudio2()->CreateSourceVoice( &pSourceVoice, pwfx, 0,
        XAUDIO2_DEFAULT_FREQ_RATIO, &m_callback ) ) ){
        wprintf( L"Error %#X creating source voice\n", hr );
        SAFE_DELETE_ARRAY( pbWaveData );
        return false;
    }
    m_callback.set_source( pSourceVoice );

    pSimpleAPO  =   nullptr;
    pMonitorPre =   nullptr;
    pMonitorPost    =   nullptr;
    CSimpleAPO::CreateInstance( nullptr, 0, &pSimpleAPO );
    CMonitorAPO::CreateInstance( NULL, 0, &pMonitorPre );
    CMonitorAPO::CreateInstance( NULL, 0, &pMonitorPost );
     // Create the effect chain
    XAUDIO2_EFFECT_DESCRIPTOR apoDesc[3] = {0};
    apoDesc[0].InitialState = true;
    apoDesc[0].OutputChannels = 1;
    apoDesc[0].pEffect = static_cast<IXAPO*>(pMonitorPre);
    apoDesc[1].InitialState = true;
    apoDesc[1].OutputChannels = 1;
    apoDesc[1].pEffect = static_cast<IXAPO*>(pSimpleAPO);
    apoDesc[2].InitialState = true;
    apoDesc[2].OutputChannels = 1;
    apoDesc[2].pEffect = static_cast<IXAPO*>(pMonitorPost);
    XAUDIO2_EFFECT_CHAIN chain = {0};
    chain.EffectCount = sizeof(apoDesc) / sizeof(apoDesc[0]);
    chain.pEffectDescriptors = apoDesc;
    if( FAILED( pSourceVoice->SetEffectChain( &chain ) ) ){
        printf("xAUDIO ERROR\n");
    }
    pSimpleAPO->Release();
    pMonitorPre->Release();
    pMonitorPost->Release();

    XAUDIO2_BUFFER buffer = {0};
    buffer.pAudioData = pbWaveData;
    buffer.Flags = XAUDIO2_END_OF_STREAM;  // tell the source voice not to expect any data after this buffer
    buffer.AudioBytes = cbWaveSize;
    //buffer.LoopCount  =   XAUDIO2_LOOP_INFINITE;
    if( FAILED( hr = pSourceVoice->SubmitSourceBuffer( &buffer ) ) )
    {
        wprintf( L"Error %#X submitting source buffer\n", hr );
        pSourceVoice->DestroyVoice();
        SAFE_DELETE_ARRAY( pbWaveData );
        return false;
    }

    //hr = pSourceVoice->Start( 0 );
    simpleParams.gain = 1.0f;
    pSourceVoice->SetEffectParameters( 1, 
        &simpleParams, sizeof( SimpleAPOParams ) );

    pPipePre = new MonitorAPOPipe;
    pPipePost = new MonitorAPOPipe;

    MonitorAPOParams mparams;
    mparams.pipe = pPipePre;
    pSourceVoice->SetEffectParameters( 0, &mparams, sizeof(mparams) );

    mparams.pipe = pPipePost;
    pSourceVoice->SetEffectParameters( 2, &mparams, sizeof(mparams) );
}
```

Чтобы воспроизвести SoundObject есть метод

```
void    SoundObject::Play( void ){
    pSourceVoice->Start( 0 );
}
```

Многократный вызов этого метода не даёт ничего.
В данный момент звук играет асинхронно (без ожидания конца).

Callback функция. Stop() делает паузу.

```
void STDMETHODCALLTYPE  OnStreamEnd() { 
        this->pSourceVoice->Stop();
    }
```

/////////////////////
Быть может этот pSourceVoice должен играть только один раз? И в классе объекта должен быть просто какой нибудь пул/очередь на воспроизведение множества этих pSourceVoice?

Comment: `И в классе объекта должен быть просто какой нибудь пул/очередь на воспроизведение множества этих pSourceVoice?`
Да, так работает.

Comment: Если не будет иного варианта то напишу в ответе как сделать.